# WPF: power in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, textblock

I have text block with text "km2":

```
<TextBlock >Area(km2)</TextBlock>
```

How can I make "2" small and heigher such exponent I need view such on picture:
[image]

Comment: `WPF: Power in XAML` - That's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You can create `Inlines`, and set `Typography.Variants` appropriately.

```
<TextBlock><Run>Area(km</Run><Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">2</Run><Run>)</Run></TextBlock>
```

Comment: a XAML sample would help =)

Comment: The name "Typography" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".

Comment: @YaroslavShabanov What version of phone?  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.documents.typography.variants(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBlock Text="Area(km²)"/>
```

Seems to work:

[image]